# Connection timeout numbers for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In [PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html), it is written:

> The timeout value used for socket connect operations. If connecting to the server takes longer than this value, the connection is broken. The timeout is specified in seconds and a value of zero means that it is disabled. The default value is 0 (unlimited) up to 9.4.1208, and 10 seconds since 9.4.1209

So, what I understood is default value is 0 if we don't provide anything. Then what is `9.4...` and `10...` it is mentioning. Is `10` maximum time or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Those are version numbers and a new default

The numbers you are seeing in that part of the documentation (`9.4.1208`) are version numbers (see [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) for an example), eg [9.4.1208](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1208).

Note that the [JDBC driver versioning changed](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/faq.html) and now **numbers from 42**:

> #### 1.1. Why the versioning change from 9.4.xxxx to 42.x.x? We have three issues we are trying to address here.
>
> a) We do not want to be tied to the server release schedule.
>
> ...
>
> b) Avoid confusion as to which version to use with which server
>   version.
>
> ...
>
> c) The previous version policy don't leave room for differentiate from
>   bug fixes releases and feature releases.

The other bit you asked about:

> 10 seconds since 9.4.1209

Is the new default, ie the default was 0 (*no timeout*) and it changed to *10 seconds* before the connection times out.